# package androidx.core.view does not exist

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

My android assemble build is failing with this error

```bash
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:8: error: package androidx.core.view does not exist
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
                         ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:13: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;
                        ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:14: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.RenderMode;
                        ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:15: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
                                ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:16: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
                                ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:17: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
                                ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:18: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
                                ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:19: error: package com.facebook.react.common does not exist
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder;
                                ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:20: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
                                   ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:21: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
                                   ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:22: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
                                               ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:23: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager.events does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.RCTEventEmitter;
                                          ^
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
class LottieAnimationViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<LottieAnimationView> {
                                         ^
  symbol: class SimpleViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
class LottieAnimationViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<LottieAnimationView> {
                                                           ^
  symbol: class LottieAnimationView
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
  private Map<LottieAnimationView, LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager> propManagersMap = new WeakHashMap<>();
              ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override public LottieAnimationView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class ThemedReactContext
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override public LottieAnimationView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
                   ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
  private void sendOnAnimationFinishEvent(final LottieAnimationView view, boolean isCancelled) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
  public void receiveCommand(final LottieAnimationView view, int commandId, final ReadableArray args) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
  public void receiveCommand(final LottieAnimationView view, int commandId, final ReadableArray args) {
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:196: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSourceName(LottieAnimationView view, String name) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:209: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSourceJson(LottieAnimationView view, String json) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:214: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSourceURL(LottieAnimationView view, String urlString) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:250: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setCacheComposition(LottieAnimationView view, boolean cacheComposition) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:255: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setResizeMode(LottieAnimationView view, String resizeMode) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:268: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setRenderMode(LottieAnimationView view, String renderMode) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setProgress(LottieAnimationView view, float progress) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:286: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSpeed(LottieAnimationView view, double speed) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:291: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setLoop(LottieAnimationView view, boolean loop) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:296: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setImageAssetsFolder(LottieAnimationView view, String imageAssetsFolder) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:301: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setEnableMergePaths(LottieAnimationView view, boolean enableMergePaths) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:306: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setColorFilters(LottieAnimationView view, ReadableArray colorFilters) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:306: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setColorFilters(LottieAnimationView view, ReadableArray colorFilters) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setTextFilters(LottieAnimationView view, ReadableArray textFilters) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setTextFilters(LottieAnimationView view, ReadableArray textFilters) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:316: error: cannot find symbol
  protected void onAfterUpdateTransaction(LottieAnimationView view) {
                                          ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
  private LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager getOrCreatePropertyManager(LottieAnimationView view) {
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:195: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "sourceName")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "sourceJson")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:213: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "sourceURL")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:249: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "cacheComposition")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:254: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "resizeMode")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "renderMode")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "progress")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:285: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "speed")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:290: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "loop")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:295: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "imageAssetsFolder")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:300: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "enableMergePathsAndroidForKitKatAndAbove")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:305: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "colorFilters")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
/Users/alitamoore/github/snackpass/snackpass-client-rn70/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/LottieAnimationViewManager.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "textFiltersAndroid")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
```

Here's my system / react-native enviornment

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0.1
    CPU: (10) x64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 16.15 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.21.1 - /var/folders/02/y59x6bdj1s50yv5r9gd0bkcm0000gq/T/yarn--1669348225775-0.5439433786303933/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /var/folders/02/y59x6bdj1s50yv5r9gd0bkcm0000gq/T/yarn--1669348225775-0.5439433786303933/yarn
    npm: 8.19.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.11.14.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /Users/alitamoore/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1 Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1
    Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.11 - /Users/alitamoore/.jenv/shims/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.69.7 => 0.69.7 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I'm using Intellij 2022.2.3; here's my gradle.properties file

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0

# Use this property to specify which architecture you want to build.
# You can also override it from the CLI using
# ./gradlew <task> -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64
reactNativeArchitectures=armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64

# Use this property to enable support to the new architecture.
# This will allow you to use TurboModules and the Fabric render in
# your application. You should enable this flag either if you want
# to write custom TurboModules/Fabric components OR use libraries that
# are providing them.
newArchEnabled=false

org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

(I am posting this and answer it because I had trouble finding an answer while dealing with this and similar issues in the past, this also affected older versions of gradle + react native)

Answer (score 0):

A couple proposed solutions:

- [it occurs b/c of device id -- use patch-package to fix](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/665#issuecomment-1327037532)